# Múltiplos ADD INDEX junto ou separados?

Tags: php, mysql

Queria saber qual a diferença prática entre isto, *no MySQL*:

```
ALTER TABLE `tabela` ADD INDEX `col1` (`col1`);
ALTER TABLE `tabela` ADD INDEX `col2` (`col2`);
```

Para isto:

```
ALTER TABLE `tabela` ADD INDEX `col1col2` (`col1`, `col2`);
```

Uma vez que em ambos os casos o INDEX está afetando ambas as colunas necessárias.

**Se por exemplo, utilizar:**

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE col1 = 'qualquer' AND col2 > 0");
```

Teria diferença na performance em utilizar o método de INDEX separado ou junto?
Se existir ambos (separados e juntos) teria algum beneficio neste caso, ou teria que manualmente definir o `query()` para usar INDEX "unido"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você faz múltiplas vezes a consulta que disse:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM tabela WHERE col1 = 'qualquer' AND col2 > 0");
```

Talvez seja mais pertinente fazer o índice composto. Pois ele funciona exatamente como o índice de um livro, imagina que se tem duas informações pra você achar um capítulo de um livro por exemplo, nome e número da página, logo se acha aquela informação mais facilmente, o mesmo princípio rege a busca de dados em um banco de dados.

Sendo que se consultas baseadas em cada coluna separadamente forem mais frequentes, é mais vantajoso realizar a criação de dois índices.

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179085/multiple-indexes-vs-multi-column-indexes

Comment: O ideal é salvar os dois tipos. Depois de 10 dias de uso verifiquei isso. Simplesmente o index unido passou a demorar **3 SEGUNDOS** para concluir o query. Adicionei dois indexes sozinhos. Puf. Abaixou para **0,156 segundos**. Um resultado razoável.

Comment: Sem dúvida aumentaria o processamento, esse tipo de índice, pois é uma string. ao contrário do numeral que corresponde a um inteiro.